# Margin of main container set to 0 yet there is still a margin

Tags: css, margin

I tried css stylesheet reset which didn't do anything, and other solutions but to no fix. Margins are set to 0 on container and there is still a margin on the right hand side. If i disable the margin left 0 the extra whitespace appears on the left side.  Thanks in advance.

[image: picture of the problem]

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
#content {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
#content-left {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  background-color: #666666;
  width: 30%;
}
#content-right {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container" id="main">
    <div id="content">
      <div id="content-left">
        <div>LEFT</div>

      </div>
      <div id="content-right">
        <div>RIGHT</div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Given code works just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/w53Lorh9/  May be your other styles causing the problem.

Comment: Add `width: 100%` to your `.container`

Comment: you have problems in styles of .container... you have used margin-left: 0 auto; which is wrong.. margin-left: 0; or margin-left: auto; is correct..
you can't use 0 auto at a time with margin-left...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the margin for all elements to 0px, this will remove the extra margin

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Also add `width: 100%` to your `.container`

**Note:** Add this as the first style in your CSS. This can be overridden by the styles specified below.

**Below is an update to your code.**

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
#content {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
#content-left {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  background-color: #666666;
  width: 30%;
}
#content-right {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container" id="main">
    <div id="content">
      <div id="content-left">
        <div>LEFT</div>

      </div>
      <div id="content-right">
        <div>RIGHT</div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: * {
  margin: 0px;
} this will create issues with his current styles.

Comment: @Alok : This can be overridden by the styles specified below.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the width of the #content div to 100% will fix your problem. It's not a margin issue. For the width % to work on the inner divs, it needs a container width to base off of.

```
#content{
    overflow: auto;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You are correct, but changing this to content didn't fix it I had to change it to the (.container) since it was the overall div thanks.